# I got nothing from get Checkbox Value in Listview

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

here is my aspx page :

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewHRDFormIzin" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataStaffHRDFormIzin" DataKeyNames="STAFF_NIK" EnableViewState="false">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered striped data" align="left">
            <thead style="background-color: #4877CF">
                <!-- add checkbox -->
                <th style="text-align: center; color: white">Check</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; color: white">NIK</th>
            </thead>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("STAFF_NIK")%>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td style="text-align: center">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" Text='DETAIL' CommandName="Select" runat="server"><img src="img/detail.png" width="50px" height="50px" /></asp:LinkButton></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>Data Izin Karyawan Tidak diketemukan</EmptyDataTemplate>
    <EmptyItemTemplate>Data Izin Karyawan Tidak diketemukan</EmptyItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" Visible="true" runat="server"
    Text="Get Data" class="btn btn-success" />
```

here is my vb class:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'get data from chekced checkbox
    Dim ChkValue As New List(Of String)()
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListViewHRDFormIzin.Items
        Dim ck As CheckBox = DirectCast(item.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
        If ck.Checked Then
            ChkValue.Add(DirectCast(item.FindControl("lbl"), Label).Text)
        End If
    Next
    For Each itms As String In ChkValue
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Value Selected: " + itms + "')</script>")
    Next

    Response.Write("<script>window.location.href='HRDFORMIZIN.aspx';</script>")

End Sub
```

also i have add this code to my page load :

```
If IsPostBack = False Then
    ListViewHRDFormIzin.DataBind()
End If
```

what else am i missing ? when i hit the button1, its just do nothing. i mean, no value were get. its just go to the :

```
Response.Write("<script>window.location.href='HRDFORMIZIN.aspx';</script>")
```

i am trying to get the value of each row were checked by retrieve the value from label with ID = 'lbl'. but the button1 always got nothing

Answer (score 0):

The listview lost its data on postback because you set the `EnableViewState="false"`. Try setting it to `true`.

Comment: still do the same, i got nothing on postback just response to the homepage

Comment: I tried your code above, and the only thing I need to change is the EnableViewState property to make it work on my machine.

Comment: after long journey i found the issue why its not working. but actualy i dont have any clue why its not working at all. when i remove the datatable plugins id on my listview table template, its work like charms. but when its have datatable plugin id suddenly its not work. any idea why? i think datatable only work on client side @ajakblackgoat

Comment: what do you mean by **remove the datatable plugins id**? @RizkyRRTandasan

Comment: yep, as a problem of all datatable plugins by Jquery. its the cons of using datatable(from this forum, but forgot the url), we can not get the checked value from another paging number of the table . thats why i removed the id , and i think i sholud do filter and pagination by manual with javascript not with plugins.@ajakblackgoat